# Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined? and pusher is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, pusher

There are 2 errors in my javascript.

Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined script.js:1

Uncaught ReferenceError: Pusher is not defined script.js:4

And code below is jquery reference in header.

```
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/script.js') }}"></script>
```

also, i import 'pusher' in python file.
How can i solve this??

Comment: Are you sure scripts' `src` are correct ones? It looks like after processing they point to nowhere, so libraries are not included.

Comment: Check the js files are actually downloaded (e.g. using the network tab in the F12 Chrome debug tools).

Answer (score 0):

Try to look in to source and check if your page contains jquery-1.11.1.min.js which you have included. $ not defines generally comes when JQuery lib is not included.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're maybe using Flask. If that is the case then the errors could be because you're not loading all of the scripts, or because they're not being loaded in the correct order.

If you open the console are there any errors about scripts not being able to be loaded?

Perhaps you could link to or copy and paste the first 10 lines or so of `script.js` so that we can better gauge where your errors are coming from.